# regex to select before semi colon

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Input string

```
key=value ; export key
```

want to select just `value`

regex `[^=]*;` giving including `;`. How can I remove that ?

```
sed '/key/ s/[^=]*;/myValue/' fileName
```

will above command work to replace `value` with `myValue` in line having `key` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/\(key=\)[^; ]*/\1myValue/' file > newfile
```

The `\(key=\)[^; ]*` pattern matches and captures in Group 1 the `key=` substring and then matches any zero or more chars other than spaces and semi-colons. The `\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the Group 1 value, so `key=` is kept in the result.

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/wdL7Jl):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='key=value ; export key'
sed 's/\(key=\)[^; ]*/\1myValue/' <<< "$s"
# => key=myValue ; export key
```

Comment: [^; ]* means read everything before ; ? can you please explain this ?

Comment: @FreshTransistor `[^; ]*`  = `[^; ]` - any char other than a `;` and space, `*` - zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for:

```
 sed -E '/^key=/s/=[^;]*/=myvalue/'
```

Comment: Don't.  Using an automated tool chain to edit files is a terrible idea.  Write your output to another file.  If needed, move the file over the first (but don't do that either).  If you wish to ignore good advice and much accumulated best practice, you can use `sed -i`.  But don't.  Really.  It will seem like a simple short term solution, but it will cause great pain in the future.

Comment: I'm want to keep updating this myValue and using it in shell script for my further reference. If editing a file is not good, then what you'll suggest ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to make `myValue` a parameter to a script.